# How to count AVG of rows in c# program with sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing program for school where when you press Count button it will count average grades of student with ID that is written in textbox.

I wrote this code so far :

```
richTextBox1.Clear();

SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection(Konekcija.konString);

SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand("SELECT AVG (*) FROM Ocene1 WHERE UcenikID=1 ", konekcija);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

try
{
   konekcija.Open();
   sb.Append("\n\r\n\r" + "Prosecna ocena za ucenika sa ID = 1 je:");

   if (tbID.Text == "1")
   {
       decimal average = (decimal)komanda.ExecuteScalar();
       richTextBox1.Text = average.ToString();
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    konekcija.Close();
}

richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

but this isn't working and I don't know how to calculate average of rows because AVG count average of columns and I need AVG or row with ID that is requested except first column that is ID column.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Try to use `AVG(name_of_the_column_where_the_notes_are_stored)` instead of `avg(*)`

Comment: Hello, but I don't need AVG of column, I need AVG of whole row with ID that is written in textbox. When I write in AVG(names_of_all_columns_that_I_need_to_count_AVG) I get message "The AVG funcition requires 1 argument(s)"

Comment: what is the structure of the `Ocene1` table ?

Comment: Try `select (column1+column2+column3....)/number_of_columns from Ocene1 where UcenikID = 1`

Comment: This is what table Ocene1 looks like https://imgur.com/QSznRHq

Comment: I did that: ("SELECT AVG (Srpski + Matematika + Biologija + Fizika + Hemija + Istorija + Fizicko) FROM Ocene1 WHERE UcenikID=1 ", konekcija) and i got message specified cast is not valid.

Comment: You don't need to use AVG, because the `UcenikID` is primary key, so you have only one row for the id=1, just make sure that type of columns is numeric (int, float ...). Otherways, convert the columns to float or real using `(convert(real, Srpski) + convert(real, Biologija ) .....)/number_of_columns` nad don't forget to devise the result on the number of columns